# How do I fix the size of my array?

Tags: c++, arrays

everyone. I am struggling with understanding why my numbers variable keeps outputting 1. I am trying to double the size anytime the number of elements is equal to the size of the array but I end up not getting anywhere near that part of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int selection;
    int size = 2;
    // Initializing the array
    int *dArray;
    int v = 0;
    int i, j, temp;
    dArray = new int[size];
    dArray[0] = 2;
    dArray[1] = 3;
    int numbers = sizeof(dArray) / sizeof(dArray[0]);
    do {
        // Printing the menu
        cout << "1) Print Elements" << endl;
        cout << "2) Add Element" << endl;
        cout << "3) Delete Element" << endl;
        cout << "4) Return Size" << endl;
        cout << "5) Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your selection number: ";
        cin >> selection;
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:
            // Outputting the elements
            for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) 
            {
                cout << dArray[i] << ", ";
            }
            cout << dArray[size - 1] <<endl;
            cout << numbers << endl;
        break;
        case 2:
            // Asking for another element
            cout << "What number shall be put into the array? \n";
            cin >> v;
            if (numbers== size)
            {
                // If the size is too small...
                int *nArray = new int[2 * size];
                for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                {
                    nArray[i] = dArray[i];
                }
                delete[] dArray;
                dArray = nArray;
                // Finished creating a new array
                cout << "Array size expanded to " << 2 * size << endl;
                // Adding the element
                dArray[size] = v;
                size = 2 * size;
                // Sorting the elements
                for(i=0;i<numbers;i++)
                {
                    for(j=i+1;j<numbers;j++)
                    {
                        if(dArray[i]>dArray[j])
                        {
                            temp =dArray[i];
                            dArray[i]=dArray[j];
                            dArray[j]=temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Adding the element
                dArray[size] = v;
                size = 2 * size;
                // Sorting the elements
                for(i=0;i<numbers;i++)
                {
                    for(j=i+1;j<numbers;j++)
                    {
                        if(dArray[i]>dArray[j])
                        {
                            temp =dArray[i];
                            dArray[i]=dArray[j];
                            dArray[j]=temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        break;
        }
    } while (selection!= 5);
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;

}
```

Does anyone know why the sizeof function keeps acting this way?

Comment: Do you know the size of a pointer?  And the size of an `int`?  I suspect that you think `dArray` is an array.  It's a pointer.

Comment: `sizeof(dArray)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the pointed array.

Comment: What is wrong with just using `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @DrewDormann What would I use to get the size of the pointer then?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux How would I find the size of the pointed array then?

Comment: @Confused -- What do you mean by "get the size of the pointer"?  You're doing that now, and it's wrong anyway.  You can't get the number of entries you allocated by using a pointer.  That's why container classes such as `std::vector` exists.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Alright. Well, I'll figure out how to use std::vector then. Thank you.

Comment: Pointers are pretty dumb. They know roughly what something is and where it is where it is, but they have no clue how many there might be.

Comment: @Confused _"Well, I'll figure out how to use std::vector then."_  Well, it's [**open like a book**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and splattered with examples all over the interwebz.

Comment: @TheDude I know. I just said I'll figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** the size of your array.  It's the size of a pointer, divided by the size of an `int`.

```
int numbers = sizeof(dArray) / sizeof(dArray[0]);
```

This is the size of the array in your program.

```
int numbers = size;
```

Comment: So how would I find the number of elements in dArray?

Comment: @Confused `size`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(dArray)` gives you the size of `dArray`. `dArray` is defined as `int *dArray`, so its size is `sizeof(int*)`. That doesn't change, regardless of what the pointer points to. That's different from an actual array; your size code would work correctly with `int dArray[3];`.

To get the size of the array, just use your `size` variable; that's the number of `int` objects that were allocated.

Even better, use `std::vector<int>;` its `size()` member function tells you how many elements it has.

Comment: Alright. I'll work on trying to learn std::vector. Thank you for telling me that.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numbers = sizeof(dArray) / sizeof(dArray[0]);
```

Numbers is resolving to 1 because dArray is a pointer to the start of your array, not the array itself.  When you call sizeof() you are getting the size of the pointer, not the array.  On a 32 bit application, the pointer is 32 bits (4 bytes) and your first int is also 32 bits (4 bytes).  So what this statement resolves to is

```
int numbers = 4 / 4;
```

leaving 1.  If you instead declared an array of doubles then sizeof(dArray[0]) would be 8 but the size of the pointer would still be 4, so the statement would resolve to numbers = 4 / 8 = .5, but since numbers is an int it would just resolve to 0.  So your code would still break, but in new exciting ways.

Interestingly enough, if you compiled this as a 64 bit application sizeof(dArray) would be 64 bits (8 bytes), so you would get numbers = 8 / 4 = 2 as you expected.  Then you would double your array size and your code would break because numbers would resolve to 2 which would potentially be even more confusing, so be thankful you caught it now!

I agree with what others have said though.  If you use a Vector you can just keep pushing values onto the end of it and let it worry about changing the size of the array!

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. It makes sense now why it is 1. Well, the assignment says to use dynamic arrays and pointers so how would I go about finding the number of elements, a different variable than the size of the array, with just an array function.

Comment: There is no way to tell the size of an array from just a pointer.  Pointers are a little strange like that.  

You can say int *dArray;  dArray = new int[2]; and then say cout << dArray[25]; without any problems.  The computer just finds the section of memory that is 25 int-spaces from the pointer and gives you whatever is in memory there.  

You would have to create another variable to keep track of the last position of the array you filled in.  Then when that variable reaches your maximum size you can expand the array.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you for clarifying.